# Parsing PHP Code with PHPLY

Tags: php, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using phply to parse PHP code and have stumbled upon a few problems.

1. Visit whole AST tree

The current code is as follows:

```
   def parse_php():
      try:
        print phpfile
        # read the content of PHP file
        content = open('/tmp/index.php').read()
        print content

        # build the AST tree from the PHP file
        nodes = parser.parse(content, lexer=lexer)
        resolve_magic_constants(nodes)

        # recursively iterate over all parameters
        # TODO

      except SyntaxError as e:
        print "[-] Syntax error in file: "+phpfile
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
      except Exception as e:
        print "[-] Error: " + str(e) + '.'
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

If you've looked at the code, you can see the TODO written in there: does somebody know how to recursively visit the whole AST tree with phply?

1. Incomplete Files

The second problem are files, which are not a complete PHP files as:

```
<?php
define('THEMES', true);
require('./header.php');
```

Th header.php, then further includes the body and the footer, making the file complete. What is the best way to defend against such files and still be able to use phply to parse the PHP code.

1. Is there anything better out there, which can parse PHP code. I know a few libraries exist, but I haven't actually used them for a few years and don't exactly know whether some have been worked on recently.

Thank you

Comment: *Is there anything better out there?* You'll note that a Meta person deleted my answer, which I thought addressed your question and issues directly.   If you thought it did, even if you don't expect to use it, it would be helpful for you make a remark here to that effect.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what kind of answer did you post, but I'm looking for an answer, which can directly tell me how to traverse the AST tree with phply.

Comment: You asked for "Is there anything better out there, that can parse PHP code".  I provided an answer to that question.  A meta person deleted the answer.  It does not answer how to do it with phply, because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: This SO answer shows a full PHP parser: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6672356/120163